# When I try to transform this player controller it just resets to the original position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a reduced version of the player controller I am using now, which still produces the error explained below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityStandardAssets.Utility;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (CharacterController))]
    public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private float m_RunSpeed;

        private CharacterController m_CharacterController;

        // Use this for initialization
        private void Start()
        {
            m_CharacterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            Vector3 move = Vector3.right * m_RunSpeed;
            m_CharacterController.Move(move * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        } 
    }
}
```

I am using the standard assets script and I am trying to have a script teleport the player to different places. When I try and move the player it goes to that position for a frame, then goes right back to its position.

```
player.transform = new Vector3(1,2,3);
// works as expected, but then next frame, player's
// position is back to where it was before
```

Comment: Nobody wants to parse your entire script for any mistakes ... rather use your really unnecessary `Filler` space for explaining what exactly the problem is, which line is responsible? Also have a look into [Debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)...

Comment: looks like the unity standard assets first person or part of... but its hard to tell what is or is not happening..

Comment: @derHugo Since this question [came up again today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66017493/1092820), I was wondering if you'd consider upvoting this question since I got rid of the extraneous stuff since you'd last seen it, to help people find it easier.

Comment: @Ryan Britt, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) my answer below so that people can find it easier. It seems to be a recurring problem worth helping people with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs because `Move` may not be able to read the up-to-date values for `transform.position`.

This problem has been reported on the official Unity Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/charactercontroller-overrides-objects-position-when-teleporting-with-transform-dot-position), and a solution was posted there as well:

> The problem here is that auto sync transforms is disabled in the physics settings, so `characterController.Move()` won't necessarily be aware of the new pose as set by the transform unless a `FixedUpdate` or `Physics.Simulate()` called happened in-between transform.position and `CC.Move()`.
>
> To fix that, either enable auto sync transforms in the physics settings, or sync manually via `Physics.SyncTransforms` right before calling `Move()`

So, you could fix your problem by editing `FixedUpdate` so that it calls `Physics.SyncTransforms` before `Move`, like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityStandardAssets.Utility;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (CharacterController))]
    public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private float m_RunSpeed;

        private CharacterController m_CharacterController;

        // Use this for initialization
        private void Start()
        {
            m_CharacterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            Vector3 move = Vector3.right * m_RunSpeed;

            Physics.SyncTransforms();
            m_CharacterController.Move(move * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        } 
    }
}
```