# transform.position doesn't move player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `Player` (made out of an cylinder, some `FirstCam`, `SecondCam` and `ThirdCam`, for switching views when pressing a certain key - doesn't matter), which is located on a cube (wide enough to take a walk on it). There's nothing else below the cube.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

This is the `Player`'s structure:

[image]

This is the inspector for `Player`:

[image]

I have the following script `ResetToInitial.cs`, attached to my `Player`:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResetToInitial : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3 pos;
    void Start() {
        pos = transform.position;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (transform.position.y < -10) {
            transform.position = pos;
        }
    }
}
```

and also some movement script `PlayerMovement.cs` that allows him to move up, down, left, right, jump and sprint.

This is `PlayerMovement.cs`:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public CharacterController controller;
    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public TextMeshPro State;
    public TextMeshPro State2;
    public TextMeshPro State3;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        float groundDistance = 0.4f;
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0) {
            velocity.y = -2f; 
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float g = -20f;
        float jumpHeight = 1f;
        float speed = 6f;
        
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
            speed = 8f;
            State.text = "running mode";
            State2.text = "running mode";
            State3.text = "running mode";
        } else {
            speed = 5f;
            State.text = "walking mode";
            State2.text = "walking mode";
            State3.text = "walking mode";
        }

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && isGrounded) {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * g);  
        }
        velocity.y += g * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

`ResetToInitial.cs` is intended to teleport the `Player` to the initial position (back on the cube, the position recorded when the scene loads), after he falls of the cube. The problem is `transform.position` won't move the player anywhere. It won't do anything. I tried to output something in the last if to see if it works, and the output was printed, but still no teleportation happened.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Question does not include enough steps to make the Player "falls of the ground". Please include all steps necessary to reproduce the problem. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: It should work. Unless your script is attached to a different gameobject than the player where the cylinder is located in

Comment: @Ruzihm Thank you. Edited my question

Comment: @Arrcival But it doesn't. `Player` is made out of `Cylinder`, `FirstCam`, `SecondCam` and `ThirdCam` (used them for switching views when pressing `V` key). I attached `ResetToInitial.cs` to `Player`, and nothing's happening

Comment: Let me be more clear. I can only guess that whatever is responsible for your player's movement is overriding the transform.position assignment but it is impossible for me to suggest a helpful solution, because the question is incomplete. See [mre] for more information.

Comment: @Ruzihm I also provided the code for my `PlayerMovement` script

Comment: @MarioMateas Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59270616/1092820) answer your question?

Comment: @Ruzihm Yup. Added `Physics.SyncTransforms();` before `Move()` in the `PlayerMovement.cs` script, and it works now. Thank you so much! Should've searched a bit more...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I try to transform this player controller it just resets to the original position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270616/when-i-try-to-transform-this-player-controller-it-just-resets-to-the-original-po)