# setting player go.transform.position not changing position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Trying to move a player object to the start location built into each level of the game at level start but the object does not reposition. The player is not a child of another so I am working with root transform here.

```cs
//move player to start position (I know find is expensive)
startPosition_GO = GameObject.Find("StartPosition");
playerGO.transform.position = startPosition_GO.transform.position;

//and just to be because
playerGO.transform.position = new Vector3(startPosition_GO.transform.position.x, startPosition_GO.transform.position.y, startPosition_GO.transform.position.z);
```

player object stays where it was and does not move. [image]

including two images, first before starting the level you can see the starting location game object (the pink square). The code above is called at level start. The second image shows where the player (with the arrow nav icon on it sits after the code is executed. [image]

Comment: Debugging questions on stack overflow require a [mre] to be on topic. See [ask] for more information. Your problem does seem familiar so I will take a guess at the cause. [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59270616/1092820)?

Answer (score 0):

Try just this code to move the player position.

```
startPosition_GO = GameObject.Find("StartPosition");
playerGO.transform.position = startPosition_GO.transform.position;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have in place and it isnt repositioning for some reason. I am adding a scene additively and wondering if that has something to do with this odd impact. I may just have to instantiate the player object at the position instead of moving it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the position once. You could remove this

```
playerGO.transform.position = new Vector3(startPosition_GO.transform.position.x, startPosition_GO.transform.position.y, startPosition_GO.transform.position.z);
```

Or this and it should work.

```
playerGO.transform.position = startPosition_GO.transform.position;
```

The code seems redundant which could lead to issues.

Comment: Yes I know its redundant. I should have known not to include that in my post, but it was to demonstrate either should work but they are not. Really cant figure out why this is not working. Its not complex. Its a standard positioning. All I can think of is something is null but no error is being thrown.